# has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: jquery, node.js

my visual studio one solution in two project 1 is mvc4 project and 2 is node js project..
i am trying to get the data on object in node js project and this function call in my front end page in my mvc project ...
for e.g
first project port is http://localhost:1011 - this is mvc project 
first project port is http://localhost:3215  - this is node js Project

following jquery call in my on click button event front end

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3215/?Id=8014' from origin 'http://localhost:1011' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. please suggest me how to resolve this error.....

jquery :-

```
 function abctest(Id) {
        alert(1);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:3215',
            timeout: 3000,
            dataType: 'application/json',
            data: {Id:Id},
            success: function (data) {
                //show content
                alert('Success!')
            },
            error: function (Error) {
                alert(Error);
            }
        });
    }
```

server.js:-

```
var express = require('express');
let $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
var app = express();
var libraryData;
var cust_dynamicdata;
global.abcdObj = { projectDir: __dirname };

var server = app.listen(3215, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
app.get('/', function (req, response) {
    libraryData = require(__dirname + '/build/Release/mylib');
    cust_dynamicdata= new libraryData.abc(__dirname + "/");
    response.send('test');
});
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:1011');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this on firefox ?

Comment: @ThivankaW no sir , i am used in chrome browser....

Comment: Can you please try and let me know ? run in firefox and tell me ...thanks

Comment: @ThivankaW  same issue sir

Comment: i think may be something wrong in my jquery function because if i am trying to node js project data show in postman